# SQL Server: create rows with info from multiple tables having the same column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am doing an integration with a customer's ERP. The database tables have a normalization so that the columns that have the same name throughout any table, must have the same data type.

With this premise, I would like to generate a SQL, or a stored procedure that drags data from several source tables in a given order always matching the column names, to 2 target tables. As it is highly probable that the ERP vendor will add new columns without notifying my department, I need the columns to be obtained dynamically.

All this is to generate a single record in a table (in this case, the head data of a purchase to a supplier), and several rows in another table (the items of the purchase).

My idea is to have an auxiliary table where I put the information coming from my system, and then, execute that SQL/procedure to consolidate the information into the ERP purchase tables.

Let's take an example.

My tables would have information similar to this

(Purchase header)

```
ExternalOrderId | SupplierCode | PurchaseDate        | PurchaseStatus | FiscalYear | Series
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ABCD            | 00001        | 2021-12-11 12:00:00 | DRAFT          | 2021       | S
```

(Purchase items)

```
ExternalOrderId | ArticleCode | ItemOrder | Units
--------------------------------------------------
ABCD            | 1234        | 1         | 2
ABCD            | 2345        | 5         | 4
ABCD            | 3456        | 10        | 10
ABCD            | 1234        | 15        | 3 (very important, same article can be repeated multiple times in one purchase)
.....
ABCD            | 9999        | 100       | 10
```

Very important step is to take fiscal year, series and number from a table of counters.   The counter should be incremented after the process.

Example of table "Counters" (note that there may be several numbers for one type depending on the series and the exercise):

```
Type             | FiscalYear | Series | LastNumber
----------------------------------------------------
SupplierPurchase | 2021       | S      | 26
SupplierPurchase | 2021       | A      | 60
SupplierPurchase | 2021       | B      | 15
SaleOrder        | 2021       | S      | 19
SaleOrder        | 2021       | X      | 200
```

Table "Accounting data".

```
SupplierCode | AdditionalColumn1 | AdditionalColumn2 | AdditionalColumn3
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
00001        | AC1A              | AC2A              | AC3A
```

Table "Company data".

```
SupplierCode | AdditionalColumn2 | AdditionalColumn3 | AdditionalColumn4
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
00001        | AC2B              | AC3B              | AC4B
```

Table "Supplier data".

```
SupplierCode | AdditionalColumn3 | AdditionalColumn5
-----------------------------------------------------
00001        | AC3C              | AC5C
```

In this case the result should be something like this: for the columns with the same name, the data coming from the last table read should be kept. For example, AdditionalColumn1, will have the value of the first table (AC1A) because is the only table with that column name, and in the case of AdditionalColumn3, the data from the last one (AC3C).

The final result should look something like this:
Purchase Header

```
FiscalYear | Series | Number | SupplierCode | AdditionalColumn1 | AdditionalColumn2 | AdditionalColumn3 | AdditionalColumn4 | AdditionalColumn5 | PurchaseStatus | PurchaseDate           | ExternalPurchaseID
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2021       | S      | 27     | 00001        | AC1A              | AC2B              | AC3C              | AC4B              | AC5C              | DRAFT          | 2021-10-11 12:00:00:00 | ABCD
```

Note that the purchase number is 27, because in the counters table the last number used for the series "S" was 26. After creating this row, the counter must be set to 27.

In the case of the purchase items, it would be the same, obtaining the data from:

- The purchase header created in the previous step.
- Data from the Articles table
- Data from another table with additional information about the articles.
- The data from the purchase items table that I generated earlier.

But in this case, instead of being a single record, it will be a record for each item that I reflect in my auxiliary table, matching the info by the item's "ArticleCode".

I could do all this through programmed code, but I would like to abstract from the programming language and include all this in the database logic, to make a very fast, transactional process that can be retried in case of failure. Besides, as I said, they will be dynamic columns, since the ERP provider will be able to create new columns. In this way, I will not have to worry about having to escape the information of possible unicode characters and I will be sure that the data types are respected at all times.

It would be nice if i can get a boolean flag marked on my auxiliary table to indicate that the purchase has been consolidated correctly.

Thanks in advance

### **EDIT**

As @JeroenMostert said in one response this question is too vague. The purpose of my question is to know how to use the column names obtained, for example from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`, from a table `A` and use them in a query, but only the ones that intersect with the columns of a table `B`, and do it several times with several tables so that I can generate the header of the purchase. And then use the same process (and the resulting data) to generate the purchase rows.

Comment: T-SQL hates dynamic queries. It needs to know the exact shape of all result sets in advance for all but a handful of operations. Combined with its poor support for string handling, this means trying to have dynamic code exclusively on the database end is a recipe for suffering. That's the general advice -- as for specifics, I would say this question is far too broad to admit an answer -- indeed I have no idea what your question *is*, beyond "can you tell me anything at all to make this happen somehow". Try implementing this; if you run into trouble, come back with specifics.

Comment: Thank you for your response @JeroenMostert, I'll edit my question with something more specific.

Comment: A few tips to get you going: in dynamic SQL, always use `QUOTENAME` on table and column names, always parameterize actual data variables via `sp_executesql`, use `sys.tables` etc instead of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, use `FOR XML` or `STRING_AGG` to aggregate column names instead of `SELECT @var = @var +...`